# .htaccess redirecting index.php to root for main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect only my domain index.php file to root of the website, like this:

**www.domain.com/index.php** to **www.domain.com**

but not for my subdomains, like this one:

**shop.domain.com/index.php**.

Here is my code:

```
#Rewrite non www to www, except subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^shop.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

#Rewrite index.php to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please help.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: use RewriteCond in VirtualHost sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed all links for redirection in cPanel, and some of them in .htaccess.